# How to delete SharePoint 2013 MySite UserPosts

Tags: 2013, powershell, user-profile, mysite

I've created a new web application (e.g. bloggler.myspfarm.com) on my SharePoint 2013 farm and set up my site and it worked fine. I sent 2 posts on mysite. After that I removed this web application using central admin and create a new web application (e.g. mysite.myspfarm.com) with a different name and set up mysite and it works fine again. But here is the problem, I can see my previous post on my user profile page but I can not delete this posts. I can see little X icon on post, I can click it and click "remove post" button and delete it but when I refresh the page posts come back. Is there a way to delete this posts using PowerShell?

Shortly, how can I delete a post in mysite newsfeed using powershell?

When I try to reply post, I'm getting this

```
Microsoft.Office.Server.Microfeed.MicrofeedException. Internal Error Code: 26.
```

According to [here](http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2013/02/13/internal-error-codes-sharepoint-2013-microfeed-exceptions-deciphered/?utm_source=tuicool) it means

```
MicroBlogList_Error_FetchingItem
```

Comment: Did you restore the Personal sites from the original content DBs or create new ones?

Comment: I created new DB every time when I create new web application. I did not restore any DB. Also I removed and created user profile service application and still posts there.

Answer (score 0):

I would try resetting the Feed Cache. Run the following cmdlets in this order:

```
Update-SPRepopulateMicroblogLMTCache -ProfileServiceApplicationProxy <proxyid>
Update-SPRepopulateMicroblogFeedCache  -ProfileServiceApplicationProxy <proxyid> -AccountName domain\youraccount
```

Reference:  [Manage Feed Cache](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219560.aspx)